# 'S3' object has no attribute 'put_object_retention'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, boto3

I'm trying to implement the object lock function introduced recently by AWS s3. The code works perfectly when i run it locally. But as soon as i deploy it on amazon it breaks and gives me the error. I have tried deploying it using zappa, ECS as well as plain lambda. It appears that amazon python packages don't have the latest boto3. This is the code I am trying to make work:

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key)
response = s3_client.put_object_retention(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key='docker.docx',
    Retention={
        'Mode': 'COMPLIANCE',
        'RetainUntilDate': datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 6)
    },
    VersionId='xN7ixBbDRaUoO99rpUzO6R8E30xox2Ng'
)
```

My ultimate goal is to deploy it in a flask app. But I am currently stuck as I can't even get this to work on any aws deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`put_object_retention()` is a rather new feature.

You will need to update your `boto3` to a newer version:

```
sudo pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

I just upgraded to v1.9.74 and it worked.

Comment: I have the latest version installed on my laptop so it works fine there. But when i try to deploy it aws using zappa it fails. I can probably get this to work with lambda but my goal is to have it running in flask. What would be the best approach to deploy on aws using flask?

Comment: I tried with docker and ECS but it gave me access denied for PutObjectRetention error.